# woocommerce variable product color "input type=color" html5

Tags: html, woocommerce, wordpress

I am wondering if anyone knows a way in Woocommerce Variable products to have a user select a color from a color wheel not from color swatches:

Similar to this in HTML5:

input type="color" value="#ff0000"

Where the user can select any color on the color wheel.
Then that information would be added to the order and cart for processing.

Thanks in advance